# Agrear otro elemento en getElementById

Tags: javascript, html5

Muy buenas, quiero agrear un input y poder concatenar la información del que ya tengo con el nuevo. no tengo mucho conocimiento de js.

Mi código está así:

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/qrcode.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form>

    <input type="text" id="qr" name="tx">
    <div id="padre">
            <input type="text" id="qr2" name="tx2">
          </div>


    <button onclick="generate();return false;">Click me</button>


</form>

<div id="qrResult" style="height: 100px;width: 100px">

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var qrcode=new QRCode(document.getElementById('qrResult'),{
        width:100,
        height:100
    });

function generate(){
    var message1=document.getElementById('qr');

    if(!message1.value){
        alert("Input a text");
        message1.focus();
        return;
    }


    var message = message1.value + message2.value;
    console.log(message)

    qrcode.makeCode(message.value);
}

</script>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

</body>
</html>
```

Bueno, es así como esta actualmente, el problema ahora es que no genera el código y al presionar el botón es como si se refrescara la pantalla, no exactamente lo que sucede al inspecionar la pagina al parecer si concatena, pero lo puedo ver por una fracción de tiempo muy limitada, como digo se refresca la pantalla y limpia todo.

Comment: No esta claro lo que se pregunta.

Comment: ¿Quieres concatenar los valores de tù input actual con otro input nuevo?

Comment: Actualmente genero un codigo qr basado en el input (qr), necesti agregar otro input y poder concatenar la información de ambos.  **var message=document.getElementById('qr');**acá es donde necesito poder agregar otro elemento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo puedes conseguir de ésta manera, agrego al script la libreria [qrcodejs](https://davidshimjs.github.io/qrcodejs/) que por lo que veo es la que éstas utilizando.

Agregas un nuevo input

```
 <input type="text" id="qr2" name="tx2">
```

Posteriormente obtiene el valor de lo introducido en éste

```
  var message2=document.getElementById('qr2');
```

Y por lo último lo concatenas

```
 var message = message1.value + message2.value;
```

De ésta concatenación generas tú codigo QR.

```js
var qrcode=new QRCode(document.getElementById('qrResult'),{
        width:100,
        height:100
    });

function generate(){
    var message1 =document.getElementById('qr1');
    var message2 =document.getElementById('qr2');


    if(!message1.value){
        alert("Input a text");
        message1.focus();
        return;
    }
    
    if(!message2.value){
        alert("Input a text");
        message2.focus();
        return;
    }
    
    var message = message1.value + message2.value;
    console.log(message)

    qrcode.makeCode(message);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/davidshimjs-qrcodejs@0.0.2/qrcode.min.js"></script>
<form>

    <input type="text" id="qr1" name="tx1">
    <input type="text" id="qr2" name="tx2">

    <button onclick="generate();return false;">Click me</button>

</form>

<div id="qrResult" style="height: 100px;width: 100px">
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por orientarme, lo hice tal cual me indicaste, el problema es que ahora no genera el código, cada que le doy al boton es como si se refrescara la pantalla

Comment: ¿Estás faltando importar la libreria QR?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/qrcode.js"></script> `

Comment: si lo estoy haciendo

Comment: Podrías agregar tú nuevo código en la pregunta, para ver cómo se encuentra actualmente.

Comment: lo puedes revisar ahora?

Comment: var message2=document.getElementById('qr2'); te falta obtener el valor del otro input.

Comment: también qrcode.makeCode(message); fijate en el ejemplo de mi respuesta y comparlo con el tuyo.

Comment: tienes toda la razón, ahora si está funcionando. Muchas Gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

El concatenar es similar a otros lenguajes, he aquí un ejemplo en javaScript, me tome la molestia de cambiar algunos nombres que tienes en tu código para una mejor comprencion.

```js
function generate()
{
    var texto1 = document.getElementById("inputUno").value;
    if(!texto1){
        alert("Introduca un texto");
        document.getElementById("inputUno").focus();
        return;
    }
    
    var nuevoInput = document.createElement('input');
    nuevoInput.type = "text";
    nuevoInput.name = "nombreDelInput";
    nuevoInput.value = "Texto2"+texto1;
    document.getElementById('padre').appendChild(nuevoInput);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="generate();return false;">Click me</button>
  <input type="text" id="inputUno" value="Texto1">
  <div id="padre">
    <!-- Aqui se creara el input -->
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```